# LF without CR on windows

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I create a string with a line feed character in it without adding a carriage return?
Using the Environment.NewLine method on a windows machine returns a CR/LF combo. I need just the LF.

I know about the VBLF in Microsoft.VisualBasic library, but as a company policy we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: Why on earth would you not be allowed to use the MSVB library???

Comment: It's considered a legacy library. I can go discuss this with architects if there is no possible alternative.

Comment: It might be worth noting to your employer that Environment.NewLine, if 'reflected' in to VB returns ChrW(13) + ChrW(10).... which uses the 'legacy library'

Comment: It seems amazing to me that Windows needs a library to do a line feed.

Comment: I'm curious to see any decent sized project in VB compile without that namespace.

Comment: @hometoast many of our projects don't include it and they are enterprise sized ;)

Comment: I would think the easier way to avoid the namespace is to avoid VB :D

Comment: @hometoast Don't get me started ;) Luckily the quality of a job is more then just the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the constants in the `ControlChars` class to get the individual LF character.  Also, I would recommend using the string builder:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
builder.Append("first line")
builder.Append(ControlChars.Lf)
builder.Append("second line")
builder.Append(ControlChars.Lf)
builder.Append("third line")
```

Comment: ControlChars enumeration is also in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.  Otherwise, this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Yes, it is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, but it is NOT legacy.  It did not exist in VB6 and it was specifically added in VB.NET as the preferred way to use special characters, since VB doesn't have the same escape sequences as C# (e.g. `"\n").

Comment: I **completely** agree that it's not legacy. If the OP can convince his employer that, then problem solved.

Comment: @hometoast Ah!  I missed that part of his question.  Well, I agree.  That's an awful limitation which needs to be argued against.  The Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace has some very important non-legacy things in it.  It would have been nice if Microsoft has separated all the legacy stuff out into its own library and namespace, but seeing as how they didn't, it's just a dumb idea to ban using any of the non-legacy stuff in that library.  `ArrayList` is pretty much legacy now.  Does that mean we should ban use of the `System.Collections` namespace???

Answer (score 0):

You can add Carriage return/Line Feed separately

```
Dim myString As String = "This is my string"

myString &= vbCr   'This will only add CarrigeReturn character
```

Alternatively you can use the ASCII code for the Carriage Return which is 13 while Line Feed is 10

```
myString &= Chr(10)    'This will add LF
myString &= Chr(13)    'This will add CR
```

Comment: Please refer to the OP. I would like to NOT add the carriage return, only the line feed. Furthermore I would like to NOT use the legacy library Microsoft.VisualBasic (where the vbCr and Chr() reside)

Comment: You have them the wrong way around: 10 is the linefeed and 13 is the carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST be stuck with that limitation you can just pull the LF out of Environment.NewLine.

`Environment.NewLine.Substring(1,1)`